# Displaying Sub Report Value on Main Report Footer

Tags: crystal-reports

**Description**
The Design of my Main Crystal Report

1. Header (Page header)
2. Detail Section
3. Footer (Page Footer)

> In Detail Section of main report I added a Sub Report. This Sub Report
>   is Dynamic Depends upon Records in DS. the sub report could be 3 ,4 or
>   even 10.

**What I want?** 
I have name of items in Sub report (Got from DataSet) that I need to display on Main Report Footer

**What I tried**

1. I used shared variable and Created formula to bind value from DataSet in Sub Report .
2. I used same Shared variable in main report.

**Code**

**1. In Sub Report**

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
Shared StringVar NameOfSender:= {Senders.name}
```

**2. In Main Report**

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
Shared StringVar NameOfSender;
NameOfSender
```

**Also In Sub Report I used the Formula above than where I am displaying name in Footer of Main Report.**

**What i am getting : ** 
there are 7 records in DataSet , and 7 Sub Reports are generated in Detail Section of Main report . But I got last name of sender on last Sub Report. I didn't get name of sender on First 6 Sub reports .

Any one Have idea Where am I wrong?